# NUC980:using spi in thread cause cpu 100%

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, arm, spi

when i use two SPI to communicate  with snesor in a thread, then it will cause CPU 100% usage in this thread(i use NUC980 developing board), and i open some Macro to trace the kernel, i get the message as follow, but i don't how to read it.

```
INFO: task acq_md->rawmt:16140 blocked for more than 60 seconds.
      Not tainted 4.4.289 #10
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
acq_md->rawmt   D c03bcc30     0 16140  16106 0x00000000
Backtrace:
[<c03bc990>] (__schedule) from [<c03bcfcc>] (schedule+0x50/0xb0)
 r10:b5b33e70 r9:c3a99c14 r8:ffffffff r7:00000002 r6:c20b0000 r5:c389d300
 r4:c20b0000
[<c03bcf7c>] (schedule) from [<c03bd2f8>] (schedule_preempt_disabled+0x18/0x24)
 r4:c3a99c10 r3:c20b0000
[<c03bd2e0>] (schedule_preempt_disabled) from [<c03bea90>] (__mutex_lock_slowpath+0x94/0x178)
[<c03be9fc>] (__mutex_lock_slowpath) from [<c03bebac>] (mutex_lock+0x38/0x3c)
 r9:c3a987d0 r8:c3a99c10 r7:c3a99c00 r6:c3a4dc00 r5:b5b33e70 r4:80016b01
[<c03beb74>] (mutex_lock) from [<c0239b60>] (spidev_ioctl+0xac/0x6d4)
[<c0239ab4>] (spidev_ioctl) from [<c00cb83c>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x43c/0x660)
 r10:b5b33e70 r9:c3a987d0 r8:00000010 r7:b5b33e70 r6:00000010 r5:c2033aa0
 r4:c2033aa1
[<c00cb400>] (do_vfs_ioctl) from [<c00cba9c>] (SyS_ioctl+0x3c/0x64)
 r10:00000000 r9:c20b0000 r8:00000010 r7:b5b33e70 r6:80016b01 r5:c2033aa0
 r4:c2033aa1
[<c00cba60>] (SyS_ioctl) from [<c000fda0>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x3c)
 r8:c000ff88 r7:00000036 r6:00000000 r5:b5b33e70 r4:80016b01 r3:00000000
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKF4y.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The Linux kernel v5.18 was recently released. Try to use it instead of 3+ years old stuff.